# How to start a .command script from a mac automator app

Tags: bash, applescript, automator

I'm trying to create a mac "app" using automator that basically calls a .command file to do all the work. The command file will be in the same dir as the .app but i'm falling at the first which is - get the current directory of the .app file thats been clicked to determine the file location of the .command file.

i've tried

```
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
echo "-- $SCRIPTPATH"
```

This just returns my users director - basically ~ 
The app itself is in a dir on the Desktop example: ~/Desktop/foo/my.app

I've also tried

```
 here="`dirname \"$0\"`"
   echo "cd-ing to $here"
   cd "$here" || exit 1
```

neither work.

ultimately i need to call `my.command` to run the command but need to know its actual position - or even relative to the app so that it'll fire. currently i get the error that it can't find the my.command as its not located in the root of my user account (since i wont have control over where it can be placed on the end users machine).

Any pointers on what i can do to solve this much appreciated.

Note: To answer - why am i using an app which has a terminal script to call a .command which is essentially a script - basically because if you do it this way a terminal doesn't actually pop up.. which for this demo is what i need to happen.

Comment: Why not just use an **Run Shell Script** _action_ and place the _code_ that's in the `.command` file there?

Comment: You can use a **Run AppleScript** action to get the NSBundle's bundlePath, but as mentioned you can also use a **Run Shell Script** action.

Comment: @user3439894 @red_menace thanks - i noted why i was doing it this way but lets for arguments sake just perform it as ask - when i place the following code in the shell script for automator.. 


```
here="`dirname \"$0\"`"

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --app=file://"$here"/mywebpage.htm
```

the same challenge exists..  `$here` evaluates to `.` meaning chrome fails with the error.. "dont' know how to open file://./mywebpage.htm

Answer (score 0):

As you did not include explicit details of your **Automator** *workflow*, saved as an *application*, I'm presenting the following as an example of how to have and **Automator** app, e.g. **my.app**, execute the e.g. **my.command** *script file*, that which is located in the same *folder* as e.g. **my.app** is.

For the purpose of the example, I created a *folder* named **foo** on my **Desktop**, in which **my.app** was saved along with the **my.command** *script file*.

The **Automator** *application workflow* uses a **Run AppleScript** *action* to accomplish the goal.

Replace the default *code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set myCommandFilename to "my.command"

set myAppPathAlias to path to me

tell application "System Events"
    set myDirName to POSIX path of container of myAppPathAlias
    set myCommandFilePathname to myDirName & "/" & myCommandFilename
    set myCommandFilenameExists to exists file myCommandFilePathname
end tell

if myCommandFilenameExists then
    try
        do shell script myCommandFilePathname's quoted form
    on error eStr number eNum
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum ¬
            buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
            with title "File I/O Error..." with icon stop
    end try
else
    display dialog "A necessary file, ' " & myCommandFilePathname & ¬
        "', is missing!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
        with title "Missing File..." with icon stop
end if
```

- **Note:** Change `my.command` to the actual *filename*. The rest of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* should not need to be modified.

[image: Automator App]

If **my.app** is launched and the  **my.command** *script file* is not in the same *folder* as **my.app**, then an error message will be displayed, e.g.:

[image: Missing File Error]

If **my.app** is launched and the **my.command** *script file* doesn't have its *executable bit* set, then this error message will be displayed, e.g.:

[image: File I/O Error]

Also, if the **my.command** *script file* does not exit cleanly, it too will display an error message, e.g.:

[image: Dirty Exit]

- The content of the error message will vary based on the content of the e.g. **my.command** *script file*, how it's coded and how it fails. This example is worst case scenario in that it lets you know something failed, but not what failed.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>